# Is there a way to seperate specific strings in a character vector and put them into another vector

Tags: r

I have a character Vector called make in my dataframe Output:

```
make <- c("AUDI", "HUSQVARNA","SYM","LEXMOTO","LDV","APOLLO","AUDI R8 SPYDER QUATTRO V10", "MITSUBISHI FUSO","JEEP GRAND CHEROKEE LIMITED CRD A")
```

I want to create another vector in my data frame, Output$model that includes those characters after the "AUDI"
e.g.

```
make  model

AUDI  R8 SPYDER QUATTRO V10
```

I know that I can separate the strings like this:

```
Output$model <- gsub(".* ", '', output$make)
```

But how would I do it so it only does this for strings that include "AUDI"
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyr::extract` to divide data into two columns. The first column would have `"AUDI"` (if present) or the entire string and the second column would have everything after `"AUDI"` (if present) or blank otherwise.

```
tidyr::extract(df, make, c('model', 'make'), '(AUDI|.*)\\s?(.*)')

#                              model                  make
#1                              AUDI                      
#2                         HUSQVARNA                      
#3                               SYM                      
#4                           LEXMOTO                      
#5                               LDV                      
#6                            APOLLO                      
#7                              AUDI R8 SPYDER QUATTRO V10
#8                   MITSUBISHI FUSO                      
#9 JEEP GRAND CHEROKEE LIMITED CRD A
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(make = make)
```

Comment: Awsome thanks so much ! How would you approach this problem if you wanted to extract two different character strings out so like with this example, also extracting "GRAND CHEROKEE LIMITED CRD A" from the model with JEEP.

Comment: @DylanJohnson Please include all the patterns that you want to include once in the question instead of extending them in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
Output$model <- stringr::str_extract(Output$make, "(?<=AUDI ).*")
```

Output

```
                               make                 model
1                              AUDI                  <NA>
2                         HUSQVARNA                  <NA>
3                               SYM                  <NA>
4                           LEXMOTO                  <NA>
5                               LDV                  <NA>
6                            APOLLO                  <NA>
7        AUDI R8 SPYDER QUATTRO V10 R8 SPYDER QUATTRO V10
8                   MITSUBISHI FUSO                  <NA>
9 JEEP GRAND CHEROKEE LIMITED CRD A                  <NA>
```

Comment: Awsome thanks so much ! How would you approach this problem if you wanted to extract two different character strings out so like with this example, also extracting "GRAND CHEROKEE LIMITED CRD A" from the model with JEEP. – Dylan Johnson 7 mins ago    Delete

Comment: Use this pattern `"(?<=(AUDI|JEEP) ).*"` @DylanJohnson

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
> df <- data.frame(make = c("AUDI", "HUSQVARNA","SYM","LEXMOTO","LDV","APOLLO","AUDI R8 SPYDER QUATTRO V10", "MITSUBISHI FUSO","JEEP GRAND CHEROKEE LIMITED CRD A"))
> df$model <- ''
> df$model[grep('AUDI ',df$make)] <- gsub('AUDI\\s(.*)','\\1', df$make[grep('AUDI ',df$make)])
> df
                               make                 model
1                              AUDI                      
2                         HUSQVARNA                      
3                               SYM                      
4                           LEXMOTO                      
5                               LDV                      
6                            APOLLO                      
7        AUDI R8 SPYDER QUATTRO V10 R8 SPYDER QUATTRO V10
8                   MITSUBISHI FUSO                      
9 JEEP GRAND CHEROKEE LIMITED CRD A                      
>
```

Comment: Awsome thanks so much ! How would you approach this problem if you wanted to extract two different character strings out so like with this example, also extracting "GRAND CHEROKEE LIMITED CRD A" from the model with JEEP. – Dylan Johnson 7 mins ago    Delete